# Remove triangle from WordPress theme Highwind

Tags: wordpress, templates, navigation, themes

The WordPress theme Highwind ([see demo here](http://jameskoster.co.uk/category/work/)) displays a small triangle below the `current-menu-item` in its navigation menu. I'd like to remove it, but I did not find any suitable attribute in the CSS file.

I did some investigation with Opera Dragonfly and found out that the triangle disappears, when I remove the CSS class `current-menu-item` from the list item.

These parts of the CSS file refer to `current-menu-item`:

```
.main-nav ul.menu > li.current-menu-item > a {
  position: relative;
}

.main-nav ul.menu > li.current-menu-item > a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -0.563em;
  color: #53a1b8;
  border: 0.563em solid #53a1b8;
  border-color: transparent transparent #53a1b8 transparent;
}

.main-nav ul.menu ul li:hover > a,
.main-nav ul.menu ul li.current-menu-item > a,
.main-nav ul.menu ul li > a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}
```

Non of these seems responsible for the triangle, so I wonder a) how does it get there and b) how can I permanently remove it in my child theme?

**Solution:** Add this to your child theme's stylesheet:

```
.main-nav ul.menu > li.current-menu-item > a:before {
  content: none;
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `.main-nav ul.menu > li.current-menu-item > a:before` class/css should remove the triangle.

Comment: Is there any specific attribute that creates the triangle within a:before? I'm asking, since I need to overwrite it in my child theme's stylesheet.

Comment: It's a combination of `content: "";` and `border: 0.563em solid #53a1b8;`, removing either of those will remove it.

Comment: Okay, `.main-nav ul.menu > li.current-menu-item > a:before { content: none; border: none; }` did the trick. Though, I don't understand why these two lines drew a triangle in the first place. Can someone explain?